# if value exists UPDATE else INSERT * with 2 non uniques

Tags: php, mysql

I've read through the other answers to similar questions, but wasn't able to understand how to tackle my issue.

The table that I'm working on contains meta keys for `"jobs"`, the meta keys and the `id of the "job"` repeat many times.

Table Structure:

```
id | job_id | meta_name | meta_content
```

`id` is unique, `job_id` *will repeat 3-10 times* with different `meta_name` and `meta_content` values, `meta_name` must only exist once per `job_id`, `meta_content` should not be relied on as it will store anything from text to email to phone numbers.

All my attempts at using  `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` fail and just create new rows, resulting in multiple `job_id+meta_name` combinations.

Can anyone help with building a query?

Comment: WHAT ABOUT USING REPLACE INTO ?

Comment: _“`meta_name` must only exist once per `job_id`”_ – so you got a combined UNIQUE index on those two columns, right …?

Comment: dammit, that's what I missed, thank you CBroe

Comment: @samitha you should mention that `REPLACE` and  `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is not the same thing. `REPLACE` would remove the an existing duplicate while `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will update it. For certain use cases it would be ok but with `CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY` it would not have the expected effect, if it should only update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> meta_name must only exist once per job_id

Then you should create a combined UNIQUE index on those two columns.

With that, `INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will work as intended for such combinations of data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to combine two unique key columns with

`UNIQUE KEY keyname (job_id,meta_name)`